# Position elements of same class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done some research in several forums about this topic but have not figured out the solution.

I want the top position of an element to be relative to another element's height. The div that contains these elements repeats with the same class, and only set position for the first div and repeat the same top for the other elements.

How can I make the .bottom-content top position, place at the end of the .top height, and be different on every .container?
I have tried with .closest, .find, .next.

This is the code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pTop = $(".container .top-content .top").height();
        
    $(".container .column .bottom-container").css({
      "top" : pTop + "px",
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
 
.top-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
 }
 
.top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
 }
 
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.bottom-content {
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content.
    </div>
    <div>other thing</div>
  </div>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</div>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content, is always different size.
    </div>
    <div>other thing</div>
  </div>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</div>
```

Comment: so you want those `1 other thing`, `2...` move down depend on the red container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot's of code, the key point is:

since you have multiple top container so calling this `$(".container .top-content .top");` will return multiple top, you need to call `.each()` to treat them separately.

`var topHeight = _self.height();` will give you the current top container's height.

Inside you call `botContainer.each()` this you will get 6 (in my example you will get 9 bottom container, you need to filter out the one you don't need to update the height so use this if:

`if (botIndex >= (bl) * (topIndex / (tl)) && botIndex < (bl) * (topIndex + 1 / (tl))) {...}`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topContainer = $(".container .top-content .top");
  var botContainer = $(".container .column .bottom-container");
  tl = topContainer.length;
  bl = botContainer.length;

  topContainer.each(function(topIndex) {
    var _self = $(this);
    var topHeight = _self.height();


    botContainer.each(function(botIndex) {

      if (botIndex >= (bl) * (topIndex / (tl)) && botIndex < (bl) * (topIndex + 1 / (tl))) {

        var bc = $(this);
        bc.css({
          "margin-top": topHeight + "px",
        });
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.top-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.bottom-content {
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content.
    </div>
    <div>other thing</div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content, is always different size.
    </div>
    <div>other thing</div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>


<div class="container">

  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="top">
      Height change with dynamically content, is always different size.is always different size.is always different size.
    </div>
    <div>other thing</div>
  </div>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 1
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 2
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column">
    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="bottom-content">
        BOTTOM CONTENT 3
      </div>
      <div>other thing</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works perfectly! But now I have other issue, pointed down in a new answer, to get the top position of the bottom-container when top also has different top position values.

Comment: @AgaDiseño you are welcome, sure, don't hesitate to post new question =D